# siFR 3, no fonctionnal issues for some Javascript params

Tags: javascript, sifr, config, sifr3

I'm trying to use siFR 3. I need set to the flash element to use max width for a text replaced. The width of flash text can use 200px MAX.

The problem of the following code is that

Here's is my test code :

> ```
> sIFR.replace(myFont, {
>   selector: '.myDiv'
>   , css: { 
>     '.sIFR-root': { 'color': '#077cd7' }
>   }
>   , forceSingleLine: true
>   , fitExactly: true                         // !!! Change nothing
>   , tuneWidth: 200                           // !!! Change nothing
>   , transparent: true                        
> });
> ```

Thank in advance for any advice or else informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the HTML element you are replacing has a max width of 200px.

`tuneWidth` *adds* to the width of the Flash movie, so that'll only make it larger.

Comment: Hi,

first thank your for the info but I've verify the CSS of the DIV, and it set to 200px.

If a delete the <fitExactly> param, no change returned.

Comment: Could you rephrase the exact issue you're having?